# why does my rigged mesh deform

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

I have rigged all my mesh and woks fine except for the eyelids. When I move the respective eyelid rig-bone simulating eyes closing, the eyelids get an odd deformation as in the picture below. I re-edited some of the polygons there as I though it could be a defect on the modelling but It stills having the same problem. 
is there a solution for this?
thanks in advance[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to do retopology of the mesh and then rig it again. Now works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert on this, but i think bones aren't really used on delecate things like facial expressions. I think something called face shape keys are used instead.

Comment: YEAH! that works. thank you very much Otto